# Async load and render a JSON with references in React

Tags: json, reactjs, asynchronous, promise, fetch

I have a React web-app, which loads a JSON file from the server. The content is then sent as props down to several components.

Some of the "nodes" in the JSON file contain further references (URLs), that needs to be loaded. Kind of like a HTML page.

I'd like to do this asynchronously, so that (just like a browser) I render what I can, and when the further references have been loaded I render those parts.

How would you do this?

What I can think this far is to have every component be robust for missing data (if a URL is found instead of the data, show "loading" indicator), and then just trigger setState when more data come in. Any better ideas? RxJS or some super library?

BTW: I'm not using Redux -- just props/state ATM.

Comment: You seem to have the right ideas. As long as you are not facing any issues without an external library like redux for state handling, you'll be perfectly fine implementing your logic without.

Comment: I've implemented it now, seems to work fine. Using `fetch()` which gives me a `Promise`, and doing `setState` in the .`then()`